# Animate map movement on bash

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a 2d map which is an array of arrays:

```
map = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I also have a list with moves:

```
moves = [[0,0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]
```

I want to print the movement on console (but I want every time to overwrite previous output, like [this](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/04/16/overwriting-console-output-in-ruby/))

So the expected output should be something like this

```
* 0 0 0 0     0 * 0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0     0 * 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 --> 0 1 1 1 1 --> 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0     0 0 0 0 0
```

I have tried some things but I can't get close to my desired output.

Comment: Take a look at [ncurses](https://github.com/eclubb/ncurses-ruby). This helps with rendering to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear the screen and wait for ENTER, try this:

```
map = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

loc = [0,0]
moves = [[0,0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]

def display_map(map,loc)
  system 'clear'
  loc.first.times { puts }
  map.each { |row| print ' '*loc.last; p row }
end

moves.each do |x,y|
  loc[0] += x
  loc[1] += y
  display_map(map,loc)
  gets
end
```

This works on a Mac. For other OS's you may have to replace `system 'clear'` with `system 'cls'`.

[Edit: I see I misunderstood the question. I think this is what you want:

```
moves.each do |x,y|
  system 'clear'
  nrows.times do |i|
    ncols.times do |j|
      print (i==x && j==y) ? '*' : map[i][j]
      print ' ' if j < ncols-1
    end
    puts
  end
  gets
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work in my ubuntu. I tried `system "clear" or system "cls"` but what it does is to move the entire output first to the right and the to the bottom.

Comment: I'm not a Unix expert, but you might try `system "clear && printf '\e[3J'"` or `system 'echo -e "\033c"',` both of which seem to work on Macs.

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you want to do.  When displayed on the console, I thought each element of `moves` was to be the `x,y` offset of the upper left corner of `map` relative to the top left corner of the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*ANSI terminal escape codes*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Example:

```
# Save initial cursor position
puts "\033[s"
puts <<EOF
* 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
EOF

sleep 1

# Restore initial cursor position
puts "\033[u"
puts <<EOF
0 * 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
EOF

sleep 1

# Restore initial cursor position
puts "\033[u"
puts <<EOF
0 0 0 0 0
0 * 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0
EOF
```

Comment: Looks like your terminal does not support ANSI codes.

Comment: Ah, I just misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Cary_Swoveland's solution with clearing the console, I manage to do it like this:

```
map = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

moves = [[0,0], [0, 1], [1, 1]]

def display_map(map,loc)
  system "clear" or system "cls"
  # loc.first.times { puts }
  map.each { |row| p row }
end

moves.each do |x,y|
  map[x][y] = 8
  display_map(m,loc)
  map[x][y] = 0
  gets
end
```